# Who is the cat-man (Fushigi-san) in Da Capo series?

Tags: da-capo

Several years ago, I had seen the anime of Da Capo (2003). I never saw season III, but I had a question during these years, in some chapters of the first season, the series showed a strange cat man (called Fushigi-san), this character reminds me of Utamaru.

[image: Fushigi-san]

Someone told me that he is Juinichi's representation, but I don't believe that.

Their appearances are very interesting and mysterious, but I don't understand their existence.

[image: mr Mysterious]

I have some screenshots of Dani Cavallaro's book, Anime and the Visual Novel. There they describe a series of the appearances of this character.

[image: Visual novel DaCapo]
[image]

I would very much like to know if anyone knows more about what is seen in the series about this character or the meaning of it.

Comment: Apparently, it's also similar to [Archimedes](https://myfigurecollection.net/item/23467), a black plush cat from [*Suika*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suika_(visual_novel)), another VN / *eroge* by the same developer of *Da Capo* series, Circus.

Comment: Thanks Aki, I didn't know that character existed. Now I find it more fascinating (: